# How can store only time from DateTime into SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

To store only time from `DateTime` into SQL Server 2005. I am using vs.net 2010 and SQL Server 2005

Like this

```
MyCurrent   DataType 
id          int
EnterDate   DateTime
Date        string
Time        string

// I want to like this STORE [Future out put]
id  ....  EnterDate             Date         Time
1   ....  4/11/2011 10:25:00   4/11/2011     10:25:00 
2   ....  4/11/2011 10:32:10   4/11/2011     10:32:10 
3   ....  4/11/2011 10:41:37   4/11/2011     10:41:37
```

So how to store only time value and how define datatype in SQL Server?

Comment: there is a lot tuttorial on web why you dont check and effort on it?

Comment: SQL Server 2005 does **not** have a "time-only" datatype yet - you need to upgrade to SQL Server **2008** which introduces the `TIME` datatype for this exact purpose

Comment: This is not a good idea at all because it violates the rule of good normalization of database. I think you could just store it together and perform separation during selects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Only time like this

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) AS HourMinuteSecond
```

Refer [Sql server DateTime](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/06/sql-server-get-time-in-hourminute-format-from-a-datetime-get-date-part-only-from-datetime/) for more

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to have three columns, one with datetime stamp, one with date and one with time only. if thats the case then

```
SELECT DATEPART(dd/mm/yyyy,EnterDate) AS Date
from table
```

this will get you all the dates from date time stamp, you can accomodate this in your insert query

```
SELECT DATEPART(hh:mm:ss,EnterDate) AS Time
from table
```

Comment: Just as a friendly suggestion, your answer would be a lot easier to read (and look more professional in general) if you used "you" and "your" instead of "u" and "ur".

Comment: @JonSkeet agreed, will definitely keep this in mind...